# Unable to create charts using bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, charts, bokeh, interactive

So I'm using the following code in Spyder to create a chart which will be displayed in a web browser:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

car = pd.read_csv('car_sales.csv')

Month = car['Month']
Sales = car['Sales']

output_file("bokeh_scatter_example.html", title="Bokeh Scatter Plot Example")

fig2 = figure(title="Bokeh Scatter Plot Example", x_axis_label='Month', 
              y_axis_label='Sales')

fig2.circle(Month, Sales, size=5, alpha=0.5)

show(fig2)
```

What I've realized is that if the x-axis values are numeric, then this code works. But my months column is in string format i.e Jan, Feb etc which is when the code stops working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: output of car.head()
   Month  Sales

0   Jan   1808

1  Feb   1251

2 Mar   3023
 and so on.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your X-axis is categorical in nature, so it needs special handling. You have to create a figure like this:

```
fig2 = figure(title="Bokeh Scatter Plot Example", x_axis_label='Month', 
              y_axis_label='Sales',
              x_range=Month)
```

More details can be found here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: Thank..but I still happen to get the following error:  E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: Sales [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='e993c68c-1afd-479a-a312-0c629046407a', ...)]

Comment: @Dipayan Can you add the output of `car.head()` to the question?

Comment: Sure, kindly check it out.

Comment: @Dipayan I've updated my answer - now it converts `Month` to list explicitly. If I use the small dataset that you've provided, it works perfectly on Bokeh `0.12.14dev3`.